# Hasse Diagram for Cartesian Product of Three Sets

Tags: relations, order-theory, products

I have to draw Hasse diagram for three sets in the picture.

[image]

Is my drawing correct?

[image]

Comment: I would have expected this to be three-dimensional.

Comment: So, you'll have three squares drawn.  How do you connect the squares together.  The right-side of the previous square connects with the left-side of the next square?  Why?  No, I would have expect left-side of previous to connect to left-side of next, while right-side of previous connects to right-side of next, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that this is an extended version of the cube $\mathbf2\times\mathbf2\times\mathbf2$ which you can find right at the beginning the following wikipedia page: [Power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set).

In your case, the product is $\mathbf2\times\mathbf2\times\mathbf3$, so you have to extend one dimension by one unit, like so:

[image]